# how to merge two mp3 files and stored it into sdcard?

Tags: android, audio, mp3, media-player, concatenation

I tried to merge two mp3 file and I followed using below urls,
[How to merge two audio mp3 file in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907109/how-to-merge-two-audio-mp3-file-in-android)
[Concatenating MP3 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597573/concatenating-mp3-files)
[How to merge two mp3 files into one (combine/join)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731155/how-to-merge-two-mp3-files-into-one-combine-joins) 
[Join two WAV files from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653861/join-two-wav-files-from-java)

I want to merge two mp3 files.

example :

File1 has 25 second long.

File2 has 15 second long.

then output file should be like 25 second long and output file must contains both files audio starting from 0 second.

**Here file 1 and file2 is stored in sdcard and both file formate is .mp3 and merged file is also mp3**

please find the below code.

```
File file1=new File(fileName);
File file2=new File(fileName2);
File mergedfile=new File(mergedFile);
mergeSongs(mergedfile, file1,file2);
```

**mergeSongs** Function is.

```
private void mergeSongs(File mergedFile,File file1,File file2){

        try {
            FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(file1);
            FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(file2);
            Log.i("merge",file1+" "+file1);
            Toast.makeText(this, file1.toString()+file2.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            SequenceInputStream sis = new SequenceInputStream(fis1,fis2);

            if(!mergedFile.exists()){
                mergedFile.createNewFile();}

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mergedFile);

            int temp;

             while ((temp = sis.read())!= -1){

                    fos.write((byte)temp);

                }

             fis1.close();
             fis2.close();
             sis.close();
             fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

**In merged file I got only file1 data only**

i m not able to understand where is the problem.

**is this possible using mediaplayer?**

Comment: To do that you must use libraries, like OpenCV, ffmpeg. Native android classes can't do this.

Comment: thanks for information ithinks using ffmpeg is very tricky process do you know any third party libraty

Comment: Try mp4parser. I had used it to merge videos. Maybe with mp3 it also do the trick :)